# load values related to selected multiple options

Tags: jquery, html

i have state select list when i select multiple states only the district of selected states must be loaded in district select list, here is my code.

please someone help me and thank you..

```
    $(document).on('change', '#State', function() {
        var locDistrict = '<?php echo @$districtList->District; ?>';
        var cstate = [];
        $.each($("#State option:selected"), function(){            
            cstate.push($(this).val());
        });
        changeCityList('#District',cstate,locDistrict);
    });

    function changeCityList(selId,cstate,locDistrict){
        var options = "";
        $.ajax({
           url: '<?php echo site_url("trusts/getCityList"); ?>',
           type: 'GET',
           data: {
                    cstate:JSON.parse(cstate)
                }, 
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data) {
            $(selId).empty();
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                if(value.city==locDistrict){
                    $(selId).append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value.city).text(value.city).attr("selected", 'true'));
                }
                else{
                    $(selId).append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value.city).text(value.city));
                }
            });
           }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this type of problems the written jquery is correct just remove the  json.parse from this line "cstate:JSON.parse(cstate)" make it as cstate:cstate.
You have to make changes in the sql query only, by doing like this i solved my problem.